# Accessing a stuct value within another stuct within another struct that is a generic in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, mvvm, struct, cs193p

I'm trying to create a card game with Swift. My model is a struct called SetGame that holds an array of cards of type struct Card where one variable in Card is another struct called content which is of type CardContent that I set to a struct called SetCard in the view model. It has the following variables: color, shading, numberOfShapes, and shape.

I can't seem to figure out how to access the cardContent variables such as shape and color inside my model.

When I type print(card1.content.shape) I get an error saying that "Value of type 'CardContent' has no member 'shape'"

When I print (card1) I get "Card(isSelected: true, isMatched: false, content: Set.SetCard(color: purple, numberOfShapes: 1, shape: "Diamond", shading: 0.1), id: 54)"

When I print(card1.content) I get the values I'm looking for "SetCard(color: purple, numberOfShapes: 1, shape: "Diamond", shading: 0.1)"

How do I access these values?

```
struct SetGame<CardContent> where CardContent: Equatable {
    private(set) var cards: Array<Card>
    private(set) var dealtCards: Array<Card>
    private(set) var score = 0
    private(set) var selectedCards = [Int]()
    
    init(numberOfPairOfCards: Int, creatrCardContent: (Int) -> CardContent) {
        cards = []
        dealtCards = [Card]()
        for pairIndex in 0..<numberOfPairOfCards {
            let content: CardContent = creatrCardContent(pairIndex)
            cards.append(Card(content: content, id: pairIndex))
        }
        cards.shuffle()
        for _ in 0..<12{
            if let dealtCard = cards.popLast(){
                self.dealtCards.append(dealtCard)
            }
        }
    }
    
    mutating func choose(_ card: Card){

        if let chosenIndex = dealtCards.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == card.id}) {
            if !dealtCards[chosenIndex].isSelected {
                selectedCards.append(dealtCards[chosenIndex].id)
            } else {
                selectedCards.removeLast()
            }
            dealtCards[chosenIndex].isSelected = !dealtCards[chosenIndex].isSelected
            print(selectedCards)
        }
        if selectedCards.count == 3 {
            print("Let's see if they match")
            print(doesMatch(cards: selectedCards))
        }
    }
    
    func doesMatch(cards: [Int]) -> Bool {
        // Get card content from id in cards array
        
        if let card1 = dealtCards.first(where: { $0.id == cards[0]}) {
            print(card1)
            print(card1.content)
            print(card1.content.shape)
        }

        return false
    }
    
    
    struct Card: Identifiable {
        var isSelected = false
        var isMatched = false
        let content: CardContent
        let id : Int
    }
}

struct SetCard : Equatable {
    let color : Color
    let numberOfShapes: Int
    let shape : String
    let shading : Double
}

class SetGameViewModel: ObservableObject {
    typealias Card = SetGame<SetCard>.Card
    @Published private var model: SetGame<SetCard>
    
    
    init() {
        self.model = SetGameViewModel.createGame()
    }
    
    var cards: Array<Card> {
        return model.cards
    }
    
    var dealtCards: Array<Card> {
        return model.dealtCards
    }
    
    
    static func createGame() -> SetGame<SetCard> {
        var cardDeck : [SetCard] = []
        let shapes = ["Diamond", "Squiggle", "Oval"]
        let colors = [Color.red, Color.green, Color.purple]
        let counts = [1,2,3]
        let shades = [0.1, 0.5, 1]
        for color in colors {
            for shape in shapes {
                for count in counts {
                    for shade in shades {
                        let card = SetCard.init(color: color, numberOfShapes: count, shape: shape, shading: shade)
                        cardDeck.append(card)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return SetGame<SetCard>(numberOfPairOfCards: cardDeck.count) {pairIndex in
            cardDeck[pairIndex]
        }
    }
    
    // Mark:= Intents(s)
    func choose(_ card: Card){
        model.choose(card)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made `content` generic, so it's type is actually `Equatable`. This means you need to cast the `content` to its actual type `SetCard`, and now you can access its properties:

```
if let card1 = dealtCards.first(where: { $0.id == cards[0]}) {
    print(card1)
    print(card1.content)
    let content = card1.content as! SetCard
    print(content.shape)
}
```

Comment: @BernardLaughlin Note that this will crash if `card1.content` turns out to not be a `SetCard`.

Answer (score 0):

You have made `SetGame` generic with respect to the contents of the cards, so presumably, you don't want your game logic to *depend on*, or assume anything about, what's on those cards, right? The game should work with any kind of card content.

However, in your `doesMatch` method, you are attempting to do *exactly that*, by accessing the card content's `shape` property. You are assuming that whatever the card content used for this game has a `shape` property. What if I used this random `Foo` struct that I just made up as the card content instead?

```
struct Foo: Equatable {
    let x: Int
}
```

There is no `shape` property in `Foo`, is there? This is why there is an error.

Judging from the method's name, `doesMatch`, you don't actually need to access the card's shape or anything like that. Why not just compare the equality of the card contents to see if they match? You have constrained them to be `Equatable`, after all.

```
if let card1 = dealtCards.first(where: { $0.id == cards[0]}),
   let card2 = dealtCards.first(where: { $0.id == cards[1]}) {
    let firstTwoCardsMatch = card1.content == card2.content
}
```

If you have more complicated matching logic, you should write a `Matchable` protocol like this:

```
protocol Matchable {
    func doesMatch(other: Self) -> Bool
}

struct SetGame<CardContent> where CardContent: Equatable & Matchable {
    ...

    // in doesMatch, you can do:
    let firstTwoCardsMatch = card1.content.doesMatch(other: card2.content)
}

// write your matching logic in SetCard
struct SetCard : Equatable, Matchable {
    let color : Color
    let numberOfShapes: Int
    let shape : String
    let shading : Double
    
    func doesMatch(other: SetCard) -> Bool {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you desperately want to access the `shape` property there for some reason, you can introduce a new protocol that has a `shape` property:

```
protocol CardContentWithShape {
    var shape: String { get }
}
```

Then conform `SetCard` to it:

```
struct SetCard : Equatable, CardContentWithShape {
```

and constrain `CardContent` to it:

```
struct SetGame<CardContent> where CardContent: Equatable & CardContentWithShape {
```

Now `CardContent` can only be something that is both `Equatable` *and* `CardContentWithShape`, so it must have a `shape` property, so you will be able to do:

```
print(card1.content.shape)
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It sounds like I should define the matching logic in the view model instead of the model.

Comment: @BernardLaughlin Please don't. If you have custom matching logic, I would suggest that you make another protocol called `Matchable`. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks, still learning swift. I will have to read up on Protocols.